# What's the order/recurrence formula/closed formula of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, recurrence

I have an algorithm called rec(n):

```
rec(n)
if (n=0) return 1
else 
    i=rec(n-1)
    A[n]=i
    return i
```

I was looking at it, and from what I can see it seems like no matter what you put in there it'll always return a value of 0, so I assumed that the recurrence relation would be a(n)=a(n-1) and the time complexity would be constant (i.e. O(1)), but I'm hesitant about my interpretation of it. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that no matter what the value of n is, `rec(n)` will always return 1. This can be proved trivially by induction using the relation `rec(n) = rec(n-1)` with base case `rec(0) = 1`.

On the other hand, the complexity of your function `rec(n)` should be `O(n)`. This is because when you compute the value of `rec(n)`, you first need to compute the value of `rec(n-1)`; but in order to find `rec(n-1)` you need to compute the value of `rec(n-2)` and so on.

Therefore when computing the value of `rec(n)`, you need to invoke `rec()` n times and hence the complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: You can also do this using a recurrence for the time complexity, something like `T(n) = T(n-1) + c` for some constant `c`.